# ANSI C TCP/IP server online client list

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I wrote simple TCP/IP multi-thread ANSI C server (client is C sharp), everything works fine except when the server doesnt receive proper signal from client it wont end the thread and close its socket (for example when client crash). Eventually it could become problem if those threads accumulate.
I got threads stored in Linked List - iterating through them isnt a problem. However they are all blocked by recv() by default and since dead client wont send anything they become stuck in memory.

What is the proper way of maintaining list of online clients? (or how to detect threads with broken connection).

```
struct tListItem {
pthread_t thisThread;
char* name;
int c_sockfd;
int run;
tListItem* next;
tListItem* prev;};

struct tList{
tListItem* head;
int count;};
```

code of thread:

```
while(param->run)
{
    bzero(&buf, sizeof(buf));
    if ((readLen = recv(param->c_sockfd, buf, BUFFSIZE, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Read error");
        param->run = 0;
    }
    else if (readLen > 0) {
        printf("%s: %s \n", param->name, buf);

        parseIncoming(param->c_sockfd, param, buf);}}
```

and here is my attempt to detect broken connection, but this causes the server to end with no message:

```
void* maintenance() {
tListItem *item;
char buf[4] = "PNG";
while(1)
{
    usleep(2000000);
        item= threadList->head;
        while(item != 0)
        {
            if ((send(item->c_sockfd, buf, 3, NULL)) == -1)
            {
                perror("Write error");
                item->run = 0;
            }
            item = item->next;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd suggest posting some actual code. That would facilitate better responses, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few common ways this is dealt with:

1. Implement a heartbeat/ping-pong in your protocol on top of TCP. That is, periodically the client and/or server
   sends a heartbeat message to the other end. If the server has not received any data or heartbeat messages within a period of time, e.g. two times the heartbeat period, or if sending the heartbeat message from the server fails, then consider the connection to be dead and close it.
2. Implement an overall data timeout. Each time the server receives data, you read time current time. Periodically you check the connection for when you last received data, and time out/close connections that haven't received data in a while.
3. Enable TCP keepalive. This is basically a last resort if you cannot do either 1. or 2.. It'll help you detect dead peers, as the TCP keepalives will break the connection if the peer cannot be reached. (Though it will not help you detect idle clients). Note that the default for keepalives is in the order of hours.

In all cases you should always to be read()/recv() or otherwise monitoring the socket for read events so you can learn as quick as possible if the connection actively breaks.

It's also quite hard to implement this if you're doing blocking read()/recv() calls, you would normally need to set a timeout on the read() so you can wake up periodically and send a heartbeat message or check if the client has been idle for too long - this is best done by using select()/poll() or the like so you can get a timeout instead of doing a block read() that might never return.